# Can I apply an amp to a JavaScript custom REST endpoint?

Tags: marklogic

I have a custom REST endpoint written in JavaScript. In JavaScript extensions, POST actions run in query mode, so they cannot update data, so I need to start a new transaction with xdmp.eval, which means I need execute permission on `xdmp.eval`. **How can I apply an amp to the JavaScript extension?**

I'm deploying the endpoint via DHF 5, so it's located in `src/main/ml-modules/services/my-endpoint.sjs`. After deployment, in the modules database, `/marklogic.rest.resource/my-endpoint/assets/resource.sjs` as been created, but also `resource.xqy` and `metadata.xml`. I actually tried creating three amps, one for each of those documents, but it doesn't seem to grant the necessary `xdmp.eval` permission. I keep getting an error message:

```
SEC-PRIV: xdmp.eval(...) -- Need privilege: http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-eval
```

As a workaround, I think I can write a wrapper around the call to `xdmp.eval` and create an amp on that. I'd just like to know if it's possible to amp the endpoint directly.

Comment: You said that you tried creating AMPs for each of the three documents, but you AMP a function, not a document. Have you tried AMPing the post() function of the REST resource module?

Comment: Um, actually I *had* forgotten that, so thanks. I think I found the problem and that was part of it, but not all.

Comment: Post an answer demonstrating the fix (and accept your answer)

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found how to do this correctly.

1. As Mads Hansen pointed out above, the amp needs to be on the `post` method in the document, that is, the local name in the amp needs to be "post".
2. The document uri in the amp needs to be pointed to the xqy document, even though my endpoint is a JavaScript one. In this case, that's `/marklogic.rest.resource/my-endpoint/assets/resource.xqy`. The sjs and metadata documents can be ignored.
3. The namespace in the amp needs to be set to `http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/my-endpoint`.

I guess behind the scenes MarkLogic executes the endpoint via the XQuery wrapper and the JavaScript module is invoked in a way that an amp on the .sjs document is not applied to it.

Comment: As an alternative, the resource service extension could import a JavaScript library that uses module.amp() to apply an amp to an exported function.  See https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/functions#id_51852